# Postfix очень долго отправляет письма

Tags: postfix

Я установил сервер postfix, чтобы потом подключаться к нему удаленно через smtp и отправлять письма. Сервер создан для проекта и доступ к нему только у меня есть.

Все работает, только письма отправляются 30 секунд (smtp запрос).

Сразу поделюсь предположением, но я в нем не уверен:
Я проверил логи postfix и обнаружил, что он пытается сделать dns resolve айпи адреса клиента. Возможно это и есть причина долгих запросов? Если да, то как это отключить?

```
Jun 28 05:54:04 host6 postfix/smtpd[4276]: warning: hostname 77-122-62-40.dynamic-FTTB.kharkov.volia.com does not resolve to address 77.122.62.40: Name or service not known
Jun 28 05:54:04 host6 postfix/smtpd[4276]: connect from unknown[77.122.62.40]
Jun 28 05:54:21 host6 postfix/smtpd[4276]: 8149C1300044: client=unknown[77.122.62.40], sasl_method=LOGIN, sasl_username=postfix@mineland.net
Jun 28 05:54:21 host6 postfix/cleanup[4280]: 8149C1300044: message-id=<1100439041.0.1593312844578@Lokha-PC>
Jun 28 05:54:21 host6 postfix/qmgr[24593]: 8149C1300044: from=<no-reply@mineland.net>, size=535, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 28 05:54:21 host6 postfix/smtpd[4276]: disconnect from unknown[77.122.62.40] ehlo=2 starttls=1 auth=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=8
Jun 28 05:54:21 host6 postfix/smtp[4281]: 8149C1300044: to=<aleksey.kovalchuk98@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:400c:c07::1b]:25, delay=0.46, delays=0.19/0/0.09/0.18, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK  1593312861 t16si8400395wmi.17 - gsmtp)
Jun 28 05:54:21 host6 postfix/qmgr[24593]: 8149C1300044: removed
```

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в сторону лимитов, например, подобное я делаю

````
smtp_destination_concurrency_limit=1
anvil_rate_time_unit = 60s
smtp_destination_rate_delay = 0s
smtp_extra_recipient_limit = 10
smtpd_client_message_rate_limit=29
smtp_connection_cache_on_demand=yes
smtp_connect_timeout=75s
smtp_helo_timeout=300s
smtpd_policy_service_max_idle = 300s```
````

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я как-то уже исправил, и уже все окей. Но уже не помню, что я сделал))